# VBA sumif with variable range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, so I have to ask you for a help.
Below, I got VBA code which should sum data from different sheet [AB] based on value from first column of active sheet. The number of rows and columns is variable, so cell adresses need to be absolute.

```
Sub sumif_test

Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
abc = ActiveCell.Row
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select

Dim mycrit As Variant
Dim myval As Variant
Dim CritRng As Range
Dim SumRng As Range

Set CritRng = Worksheets("AB").Range("A:A")
Set SumRng = Worksheets("AB").Range("N:N")

c = ActiveCell.Column
r = ActiveCell.Row

For r = 2 To abc - 2
mycrit = Cells(r, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
myval = Cells(r, c).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
myval = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(CritRng, mycrit, SumRng)

Next r

End sub
```

With this code I don't get any result.

Comment: You are using a range address as myCrit, should you be using cells(r,1).value?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. Can you think of other cell address format which could work?

Comment: have you tried, range(myCrit) or just cells(r,1)

Comment: Nathan, range(mycrit) works like a charm ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using select statements. Also learn to use the `Application.ScreenUpdating` property to speed up your code (This disables the screen refreshing between each write to the excel sheet and updates everything at the end making it much faster)

```
Sub sumif_test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NoCol As Integer, NoRow As Integer
    Dim CritRng As Range, SumRng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = Worksheets("AB")

    With ws
        NoRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        NoCol = .Cells(1, .Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set CritRng = .Range("A:A")
        Set SumRng = .Range("N:N")
    End With

    For r = 2 To NoRow
        Cells(r, NoCol) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(CritRng, Cells(r, 1), SumRng)
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've rewritten your code to avoid using the select statement. Please take a look at it and see if you can figure out what each part does.

Answer (score 0):

You need ranges and you need to set them. In your code, if you write debug.print after myval like this:

```
For r = 2 To abc - 2
   mycrit = Cells(r, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
   myval = Cells(r, c).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
   myval = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(CritRng, mycrit, SumRng)
   debug.print myval
Next r

End sub
```

you would probably get some result in the immediate window. Ctrl+G.
In order to get some result try with:

```
For r = 2 To abc - 2
    mycrit = Cells(r, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    myval = Cells(r, c).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    myval = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(CritRng, mycrit, SumRng)
    Cells(r,c) = myval
Next r

End sub
```

Finally - 2 things - [try to avoid usage of select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) and format your code :)
[Here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/664263-using-defined-variable-range-sumif-visual-basic-applications.html) you may find some examples of sumif with VBA.